# How to find the only match being stored in a regular expression variable which does not contain a specific sub-string in JMeter?

Tags: json, regex, jmeter

I have a json response as the below for a http request say x. In JMeter I am using a regular expression variable ABC which I can use post processing of the request x.

```
{"id":123,"StartDate":1446422400000,........."Status":"Ok"..........
{"id":456,"StartDate":1446422400000,........"Status":"Not Ok"......
{"id":789,"StartDate":1446422400000,......."Status":"Not Ok"........
{"id":124,"StartDate":1446422400000,........."Status":"Ok"..........
{"id":654,"StartDate":1446422400000,........"Status":"Not Ok"
```

I wish to have a regex that gives me ids 456,789 and 654 as its status is "Not Ok". Please note that the dots above indicate that there are many   characters,numbers,special characters in between.

I tried the below three regular expressions (template used is $1$ and Match No. is -1 as I want to capture all the matching occurrences) :

1. `\{"id":(\d+),"StartDate":(.+?)"Status":"Not Ok"`
2. `\{"id":(\d+),"StartDate":(.+(?!"Status":"Ok"))"Status":"Not Ok"`
3. `\{"id":(\d+),"StartDate":(.+(?!Ok))"Status":"Not Ok"`

In all the above cases, it is picking up the entire json response data from `{"id":123 till the last "Status":"Not Ok"` as a result of which I am getting only 123 stored in ABC. Can I have a regular expression that can help me extract the 3 ids 456,789 and 654 ??

Answer (score 1):

You should use JSON Path through 2 options:

- Either JMeterPlugins JSON-PATH extractor
- Use JMeter nightly build which contains a JSON Extractor that will be available in upcoming 2.14 version. This plugin work in the following way:

  - http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/easy-scripting-of-json-applications-with-apache-jmeter/

Comment: Thanks for the information!! But can I use Json Extractor in JMeter wherein I can apply some conditions ?? The Json response looks somewhat like below :

Object{l}

 > DetailList{m}

  > 0 {n}

   id : 123

   Status : Ok

  > 1 {n}

   id : 456

   Status : Not Ok

So from here as I already discussed, I want the ids 456 and all that are having Status as Not Ok.